# Javascript CPS (continuation passing style) implementation

Tags: javascript, implementation, continuations

Because of [an article in IBM Developer Works about CPS (continuation passing style)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-contin.html), I'm trying to not use "return".

without CPS

```
function getter() {
    * calculate a*
    return a;
}
function test() {
    *part 1*
    if(*condition*) {
         a = getter();
    }
    *use a*
    *part 2*
}
```

transition

the rest of the function

```
    }
    *use a*
    *part 2*
```

with CPS

```
function getter() {
    * calculate a*
    continuationtest(a);
}
function test() {
    *part 1*
    if (*condition*) {
        getter();
}
function continuationtest(a) {
    }
    *use a*
    *part 2*
}
```

the problem

A loop ends in the rest of the function.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 7):

Continuation-passing style doesn't mix well with JavaScript loops. You need to find another way to do the loop.

Note that your code is being interpreted like this:

```
function test() {
    *part 1*
    if (*condition*) {
        getter();
    }                               // <--- note indentation here
    function continuationtest(a) {  // <--- and here
    }
    *use a*
    *part 2*
}
```

So you are not currently using continuation-passing style at all. When `getter()` calls `continuationtest()`, it's probably failing, since `continuationtest()` is not in scope there.

A CPS example with a loop might look like this.

**Without CPS**

```
function doSomething(i) {
    alert("doing " + i);
}

function doLoop() {
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        doSomething(i);
}
```

**With CPS**

```
function doSomething(i, ctn) {
    alert("doing " + i);
    ctn();
}

function doLoop() {
    doLoopStartingAt(0);

    function doLoopStartingAt(i) {
        if (i < 9)
            doSomething(i, function ctn() { doLoopStartingAt(i + 1); });
    }
}
```

(The advantage of CPS is that at any point you can use `setTimeout()` to delay execution of the rest, or wait for user input to be processed, or avoid the browser from showing a "slow script" popup.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
function continuationtest(a) {
    }
    *use a*
    *part 2*
}
```

This may be what you wanted:

```
function continuationtest(a) {
    *use a*
    *part 2*
}
```

Other than that, it will be hard to help with so little information, such as what will happen in the `continuationtest`, as that could be critical if you are still having problems.